# How to send prev calendar data api send?

Tags: android, api, calendar

There are three buttons like prev, next, today. If you click on them, the data should go to the string containing calender data formattedDate.    `String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());`

```
`prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

}
});

private void requestHomeData2() {
ApiInterface apiInterface = RestAdapter.createAPI(sharedPref.getApiUrl());
callbackCall2 = apiInterface.getDate(formattedDate,AppConfig.REST_API_KEY);


this.callbackCall2.enqueue(new Callback<Callbackdate>() {
    public void onResponse(Call<Callbackdate> call, Response<Callbackdate> response) {
        Callbackdate responseHome = response.body();
        if (responseHome == null || !responseHome.status.equals("ok")) {
            onFailRequest();
            return;
        }
        displayData2(responseHome);
        swipeProgress(false);
        lyt_main_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onFailure(Call<Callbackdate> call, Throwable th) {
        Log.e("onFailure", th.getMessage());
        if (!call.isCanceled()) {
            onFailRequest();
        }
    }
});
}``
```

FormattedDate error how to fix this error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgIyo.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use this two line above the error line.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```